# Is there a way to farm haoma?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

My question is just what it says on the tin. I'm looking to start using some of the different drugs to help get my 100%, but I only have 100 or so haoma. Is there a way to farm it? If there is, what do you need to do for it to respawn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haoma, like all plants and material nodes, will eventually respawn.

Other ways to get Haoma include:

- FOB missions (both attacking and defense)
- Dispatch Missions (for your combat team, availability varies)
- Picking the plants on your Animal Conservation FOB